# Find the analytic continuation of $f(z)=\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the analytic continuation of $f(z)=\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}$. This function clearly converges on the closed disk by the usual convergence test. To continue, my strategy is to find a closed form of $f$. One thing I tried was to differentiate it to see whether its derivative looks nice enough but it failed.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that$$\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac {z^n}{n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_2(z)$$

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen this function before.

Comment: Search up Dilogarithm or Polylogarithm

Comment: Notice that $$ f(z) = -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1-zx)}{x} \, dx $$ holds for $|z| < 1$ and the right-hand side defines a holomorphic function on the region $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

$$g(z) = \frac{-\log(1-z)}{z},$$

initially defined for $z\in \mathbb C \setminus ([1,\infty)\cup\{0\}).$ Here $\log$ denotes the principal value logarithm. If we define $g(0)=1,$ then the singularity at $0$ is removable. So we may regard $g$ as analytic on $U =\mathbb C \setminus [1,\infty).$

Now $U$ is simply connected, and therefore $g$ has an antiderivative $G$ in $U.$ Actually we don't need this result, as the definition

$$G(z) = \int_0^z g(w)\,dw$$

gives us an antiderivative of $g$ in $U$ directly. Here the contour from $0$ to $z$ is the line segment from $0$ to $z.$ You can verify that $G'(z)=g(z)$ in the usual way.

Now for $|z|<1,$ $f'(z) = g(z).$ It follows that for $|z|<1,$ $f(z)= G(z)+C.$ Since $f(0)=0=G(0),$ $C=0.$ So we have $f=G$ in the open unit disc, and since $G$ is analytic in $U,$ $f$ extends to be analytic in $U.$

So there you have it: $G$ is the analytic continuation of $f$ to all of $U.$

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like under some assumptions,
$$
f'(z) = \sum_n z^{n-1}/n,
$$
so
$$
\frac{d}{dz} \left[zf'(z)\right] = \sum_n z^{n-1}
$$

Comment: So we have $\frac{d}{dz}[zf'(z)] = \frac{1}{1-z}$. Taking a brunch cut of $\frac{1}{1-z}$, we have that $f'(z) = \frac{ln(1-z)}{z}$. This seems to complicate the problem.

Comment: @Vanstar: There is no closed form with elementary function. And the integral of $\ln(1-z)/z$ is valid continuation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm.

Comment: Okay, I am confused. for $f'(z)$ to be defined here, I need to take a branch cut, which will take some points inside the unite disk off, but my original power series is defined in the whole unite disk.  How should I really solve this problem here without knowledge of the Li_2(z).